# ActiveRecord::Base before_validation with conditional not triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using `before_validation` to ensure the state of my `User` model.

```
before_validation :renter, if: 'resident? && active? && unit.present? && units.empty?'
```

The conditional is true when I tried with a new record.

```
user.resident? && user.active? && user.unit.present? && user.units.empty?
=> true
```

And the callback works perfectly without the conditional.

However, using the callback with the conditional does not work.

```
user = User.new(resident_attr_except_resident_type)
user.save
=> false
user.errors.full_messages
=> ["Resident type can't be blank"]

user.renter
=> #<User ..., resident_type: 0> # resident_type 0 because is a enum
user.save
=> true
```

Just to clarify, the `renter` method does the following:

```
def renter
  self.resident_type = :renter
  self
end

def renter!
  renter.save
end
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

I suspect two things, 1) the conditional and 2) the return from `renter` and me misunderstanding how `before_validation` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#module-ActiveRecord::Callbacks-label-before_validation-2A+returning+statements

My second suspicion was correct. `before_validation` expects truthy or falsey.

Answer (score 2):

you may try this...

```
before_validation :renter, if: :check_renter?

def check_renter?
  resident? && active? && unit.present? && units.empty?
end
```

Comment: God no! I was doing this before in another project and it was a complete nightmare. Don't make ? methods that will be used only once or twice!

Comment: @fbelanger: I agree with Sourabh that you should give this complex condition a proper name and move it into a method on its own. A condition like that is hard to read and to understand for other developers and it is harder to test. Can you please elaborate on why you think it was a *complete nightmare*?

Comment: I have to disagree. Doing this results in a massively fat model, but for all the wrong reasons. This method would never truly be reused, and is easily testable if you're writing you're tests in parallel. It much cleaner, in my opinion, to keep each incremental check separate and use combinations in callbacks. Otherwise I end up with `building_blank?`, `unit_blank?`, `active_resident?`, `acitve_resident_with_unit?`, `active_resident_with_unit_and_without_units?`, and on and on. For everything else, but this, I write methods for.

Comment: I retract my statements. In the long run, it's easier to define explicit methods that define when a model should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

IMO your callback and your `renter` method are hard to read and understand. I think it is worth it to move that code into a method on its own:

```
before_validation :determine_renter_type

private
def detemine_renter_type
  if resident? && active? && unit.present? && units.empty?
    self.renter_type = User.renter_types[:renter]
  end

  self # avoid aborting the save process by returning a truthy value
end
```

Comment: I like this solution better, than the other proposed method for cleaning up the code. Thanks! Though I'd add that this callback will fail due to the explanation in my answer.

Comment: You are right, I updated my answer. I alway mix this up with custom validator which don't break the process when returning a falsy value.